What happens to $g^{\alpha\beta}_{,\sigma}=-g^{\alpha\mu}g^{\beta\nu}g_{\mu\nu,\sigma}$ when $g_{\mu\nu}\rightarrow \eta_{\mu\nu}$ (weak field limit)?
The equation
$$g^{\alpha\mu}_{\,\,\,\, ,\sigma}\,g_{\mu\nu} + g^{\alpha\mu}\,g_{\mu\nu,\sigma} = (g^{\alpha\mu}g_{\mu\nu})_{,\sigma} = \delta^\alpha_{\nu,\sigma} = 0 $$
gives the useful relation
$$g^{\alpha\beta}_{\,\,\,\, ,\sigma} = -g^{\alpha\mu} g^{\beta\nu}g_{\mu\nu,\sigma} \quad\quad(*)$$
between the derivative of the metric and its inverse.
Here's what puzzles me. In any linearized treatment of gravity, where we assume $g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu} + h_{\mu\nu}$ where $\eta$ is the Minkowski metric and $|h_{\mu\nu}| \ll 1$, we approximate $g_{\mu\nu} \approx \eta_{\mu\nu}$ whenever it is a multiplicative factor; thus, we raise and lower indices with $\eta_{\mu\nu}$, thus:
$$h_\mu^\nu = g^{\nu\kappa}h_{\mu\kappa}=\eta^{\nu\kappa}h_{\mu\kappa}.$$
Moreover, in flat spacetime, the Minkowski metric commutes with differentiation (just as the normal metric commutes with covariant differentiation):
$$h_{\mu,\sigma}^\nu = \eta^{\nu\kappa}h_{\mu\kappa,\sigma}.$$
Now look at (*). In the weak field approximation, the right hand side is:
$$-g^{\alpha\mu} g^{\beta\nu}g_{\mu\nu,\sigma} \approx -\eta^{\alpha\mu} \eta^{\beta\nu}g_{\mu\nu,\sigma} = -g^{\alpha\beta}_{\,\,\,\, ,\sigma}$$
which contradicts $(*)$!  In other words, the minus sign, which is clearly correct in the general case, seems to be wrong in the weak field approximation where $g_{\mu\nu} \rightarrow \eta_{\mu\nu}$.
What am I overlooking here?

If the spacetime were really flat $g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}$ you would have $g_{\mu\nu, \sigma}=0$, and your derivation seems to prove this. With $g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}$ that of course no longer holds in general. I'm not sure where the mistake is for this case, but hopefully this observation is at least somewhat helpful.

I think you are making a mistake in correctly equating terms of the same order in the perturbation $h$. I would suggest expanding the metric as $g^{\mu\nu} = \eta^{\mu\nu} + h^{\mu\nu}$, and only ignoring terms of order $O(h^2)$, and then checking if the results make sense. I am not seeing any contradiction in your calculation.

First of all, we do not generally use $g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}$ when it is a multiplicative factor, but we only discard the terms of the order $O(h^2)$. Second, we have the following relation for the inverse metric in linearized gravity:
$$g^{\mu\nu}=\eta^{\mu\nu}-h^{\mu\nu}.$$
You can check the derivation of this here.
With this we have
$$-g^{\alpha\mu}g^{\beta\nu}g_{\mu\nu,\sigma}=-(\eta^{\alpha\mu}-h^{\alpha\mu})(\eta^{\beta\nu}-h^{\beta\nu})h_{\mu\nu,\sigma}$$
$$=-\eta^{\alpha\mu}\eta^{\beta\nu}h_{\mu\nu,\sigma}+O(h^2)=-h^{\alpha\beta}_{\hspace{.2cm},\sigma}=g^{\alpha\beta}_{\hspace{.2cm},\sigma}$$
in accordance with your equation (*). Note that we used $\eta_{\mu\nu,\sigma}=\eta^{\mu\nu}_{\hspace{.2cm},\sigma}=0.$
